# Issue with Array - NullReferenceException was unhandled - VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am basically trying to create an array to export checked items onto a word document. But I am getting an error saying

"Object reference not set to an instance of object."

and

"Referenced 'SelectedMutualFunds' has a value of 'Nothing'

Below is my code:

```
Public Class ExportFunds
      Public SelectedMutualFunds() As String

 Private Sub ExportFundOkButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExportFundOkButton.Click
           Dim i As Integer
    Dim array_Counter As Integer
    array_Counter = 0
    For i = 0 To ExportFundCheckedListBox.Items.Count() - 1
        If ExportFundCheckedListBox.GetItemCheckState(i) = CheckState.Checked Then
            SelectedMutualFunds(array_Counter) = ExportFundCheckedListBox.Items(i).ToString
            array_Counter += 1
        End If
    Next
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Can someone please help me solve this issue?

Comment: there is no evidence there that `SelectedMutualFunds` is ever instanced, you only declared it.  Use a List(of String) and you wont have to worry about the array size.

Comment: I declared List(of String) but now it is saying that the string cannot be converted to the list(of string)

Comment: `SelectedMutualFundsList.Add(ExportFundCheckedListBox.Items(i))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide length to your string array

```
 Public SelectedMutualFunds() As String
```

to the following within ExportFundOkButton_Click before you use, preferably just before the for loop.

```
 Redim SelectedMutualFunds(ExportFundCheckedListBox.Items.Count() - 1)
```

Comment: Am i adding that code to the button_click or replacing one of the lines that was already written in button_click?

Comment: As initially you have not given any length to the string array, you have to add the redim line in your existing button_click code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this down to a one-liner and fix the NullReference exception at the same time:

```
 Private Sub ExportFundOkButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExportFundOkButton.Click
     SelectedMutualFunds = ExportFundCheckedListBox.Items.Where(Function(i) i.CheckState = CheckState.Checked).Select(Function(i) i.ToString()).ToArray()
     Me.Close()
End Sub
```

Or, slightly longer but easier to read:

```
Private Sub ExportFundOkButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ExportFundOkButton.Click
     SelectedMutualFunds = ExportFundCheckedListBox.Items.
                Where(Function(i) i.CheckState = CheckState.Checked).
                Select(Function(i) i.ToString()).
                ToArray()
     Me.Close()
End Sub
```